# gpg: failed to create temporary file - problematic hostname

Tags: macos, gnupg

I've stumbled upon an interesting case with setting up `gpg` on Mac OS:

```
gpg: failed to create temporary file '/Users/pprazak/.gnupg/.#lk0x000060000145c100.NAME WITH SPACES.53297': No such file or directory
```

Please advice on solutions.

I've already tried:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:staff ~/.gnupg
chmod 600 ~/.gnupg/*
chmod 700 ~/.gnupg/
```

and:

```
export GPG_TTY=$(tty)
gpgconf --launch gpg-agent
```

Answer (score 1):

The temporary file that `gpg` uses for locks is derived from the hostname:

```
$ hostname
NAME WITH SPACES
```

I've fixed the issue using:

```
scutil --set HostName NAME-WITH-NO-SPACES
scutil --set LocalHostName NAME-WITH-NO-SPACES
scutil --set ComputerName NAME-WITH-NO-SPACES
dscacheutil -flushcache
```

After that `gpg` is working as expected.